# Files in Documents folder not persisting across ios builds

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm currently working on a phonegap app that stores images using the file and camera API. I'm able to take the image from the camera and successfully save it to the Documents folder. After every build using Xcode or intermittently reloading the app the images disappear.

I saved the path to the data store in the form of:

file:///var/mobile/Applications/**APPLICATION_HOME**/Documents/journals/image-1407368615295.jpg

but I notice that the **APPLICATION_HOME** changes often so i tried a relative path where I get the Documents path dynamically and store only everything else.

DOCUMENTS_PATH + journal/image-1407368615295.jpg

But again I notice that the images don't persistent across builds. Could someone explain why this is so and what could be a possible solution?

Environment

Mac OS X 10.9.4
Xcode 5.1.1
ionic
phonegap 3.5

Comment: Define "After every build"? Are you brute force deleting the app from the devise or simulator every so often by holding down on the icon and then clicking on "x" to delete it? If so then yes your app, along with everything in its documents dir will get wiped out.

Comment: yes. Oh so if I don't delete the app on the device and continue to rebuild it using xcode the documents folder should be the same as well as the APPLICATION_HOME?